# Toggle custom labels on and off in Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Added some labels to my Google Map (v3), ideally I'd like two things:

1) To be able to switch them on and off (as when zoomed out the labels become cluttered)

2) To be able to change the textsize of the label depending up the mapzoom.

I added the labels like so, info being read in from some nested arrays:

```
     for (x = 0; x < areadata.length; x++){//Start Label Loop

        labelObjects[x] = new MapLabel({
            text: areadata [x][0],
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(areadata [x][2], areadata [x][1]),
            map: mymap,
            fontSize: 16,
            align: 'center'
        });

        labelObjects[x].set('position', new google.maps.LatLng(areadata [x][2], areadata [x][1]));

     }
```

I'm using the maplabel-compiled.js from http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/examples/maplabel.html - with one change however. mapPane.appendChild has been amended to floatPane.appendChild - this brings all labels in front of any Polygons I have on the map.

This works just fine, the problem comes when I try to control the labels, I've tried interacting with the first label in the array like so with no joy:

```
labelObjects[0].setVisible(false);
labelObjects[0].set('visible', false);
labelObjects[0].set('fontSize', 48);
```

Anyone had similar issues? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Normally you would need to use push() on the array object to populate it. Does labelObjects[0] return you a label instance?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you have tried and exhibits the issue?  Should be possible, I have done something similar [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. be sure that `labelObjects` is accessible in the scope where try to toggle the mapLabel
2. there is no method `setVisible` for a MapLabel
3. setting a `visible`-property of a MapLabel will not have any effect. To show/hide the MapLabel set the `map`-property of the MapLabel to either a `google.maps.Map`-instance(`mymap`) or `null`

```js
var areadata = [
    ['label#1', 1, 1],
    ['label#2', 2, 2]
  ],
  labelObjects = [],
  mymap;

function init() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.5, 1.5),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

  mymap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

  for (x = 0; x < areadata.length; x++) { //Start Label Loop

    labelObjects[x] = new MapLabel({
      text: areadata[x][0],
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(areadata[x][2], areadata[x][1]),
      map: mymap,
      fontSize: 16,
      align: 'center'
    });

    labelObjects[x].set('position', new google.maps.LatLng(areadata[x][2], areadata[x][1]));

  }
  mymap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('toggle'));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```css
body,
html,
#map {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#toggle {
  padding: 1px 6px;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius:2px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-map-label@1.0.1/src/maplabel.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
<a id="toggle" onclick="labelObjects[0].setMap((labelObjects[0].getMap())?null:mymap)">toggle label#1</a>
```

Comment: It's worth noting some of the code referenced here.
The map label project was moved to github, here:
https://github.com/googlemaps/js-map-label

Comment: This is not working now it seems. Can any one suggest please. Thanks.

Comment: updated the code snippet with an API key and a current link to the MapLabel library (the googlecode repository was deprecated and turned off several years ago).

Comment: Thanks. will check and use this